# What is the main difference between Admob and AdSense

Tags: mobile, admob, adsense, mobile-application

I have a news website with more than 10,000 page views. I have also adsense enable on the site  and earning from the same .

Now i m planning to develope an app for my website .

How can i monetize my news app ? i heard , adsense is not allowed on mobile apps.

Do i need to sign up for admob , i already have a google adsense account.

Is it against google term and condition to earn from website as well as mobile app.

As far as i know , adsense is for website and AdMob is used for native applications,  will my adsense revenue decrease if i develope an app for my news site !

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

As you said admob is for native apps, adsense is for websites. So if you want to monetize your apps you need to get an admob account. It is not against google terms and condition to earn from website as well as mobile app, you can do both. All you need to do is to get an admob account and put your ads into your app. Then you can start earning from your app as well.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that AdSense is for websites and AdMob is for Mobile Applications. You can use both at the same time, it is not against Google's terms and conditions. You will be required to register for a new AdMob account and then link that account with your application by integrating AdMob SDK into your application. There will not be much impact on your revebue generated by your website.